# How to specify the server instance when creating a job in hangfire?

Tags: c#, asp.net, hangfire

I have defined multiple HangFire servers in my ASP.NET application [like here](http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-processing/running-multiple-server-instances.html)  all targeting a separate dashboard and when I create a job I would like to specify the server where the job has to be created and executed.

Like `BackgroundJob.Enqueue("server1", () => Console.WriteLine("Hello, world!"));`

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: There is a question/answer on the page you've linked to that addresses this. "Directly - in no way. However, you can use multiple queues to achieve this". Have you tried that?

Comment: It seems that's the only way to control the instance of execution. 

My goal would be to host several dashboards....each for one module within my website.

Comment: As mentioned by @Fermin, the way to go is to use queues

Comment: Thanks, gonna show up a sample when implemented